# How do I create a clickable image in Quasar?

Tags: quasar-framework

I would like to have an image that, when clicked, sends the user to the landing page (or another route).
In pure HTML, we can do something like:

```
<a href='route'> 
  <img src='pathToImage'/> 
</a>
```

However, Quasar's QImg doesn't have a "to" property. I have tried somewhat hacky ways to do it, such as wrapping it in a QBtn or a QItem in a QList:

```
<q-btn to="route"> 
  <q-img src='pathToImage'/>
</q-btn>

<q-list>
  <q-item to="route">
    <q-img src='pathToImage'/>
  </q-item>
</q-list>
```

This code does not show the image as I would expect. In documentation examples, they keep wrapping the images in QAvatar blocks, but then the images always have the same width and height, resulting in a square image instead of an elongated one.

Simply replacing  with  works fairly well, but then I lose all the advantages of using QImg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quasar implements [vue-router](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router) as mentioned in the docs about [App Routing](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-vite/routing/) and assume you are familiar with it. Imho it wouldn't had hurt if they had provided a simple example for such a basic use case like "linking something to x". But well here you are:

```html
<router-link to="/">
  <q-img src="path/to/image" />
</router-link>
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me the correct way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

After a strike of luck, I managed to find the solution. I leave it here so that it might help others facing the same problem:

```
<q-img src='pathToImage'>
  <div class="absolute-full transparent">
    <q-list class="absolute-full transparent">
      <q-item to="route" class="absolute-full transparent"></q-item>
    </q-list>
  </div>
</q-img>
```